# PHP: searching in the first "column" of an array of arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array of arrays and I want to copy the first column

The data looks like this:

```
(0 => "homer",   1 =>  1,   2 =>  2,   3 =>  3)
(0 => "marge",   1 =>  2,   2 =>  4,   3 =>  8)
(0 => "bart",    1 =>  6,   2 =>  2,   3 =>  7)
(0 => "lisa",    1 => 16,   2 => 20,   3 => 71)
```

Is there a PHP function (similar to array_search) which I can use to search for a name match in the first "column" ?

The data in the first column is already sorted so if I could copy "column1", I could carry out a array_search (which I assume uses a bsearch, rather than a naive element by element iteration).

My questions are:

- Is there a PHP function similar to array_search, which I can use to search for matching items in the 1st column of the 2D array?
- Failing that, is there a PHP function to copy the first column into a 1D array (whilst preserving order) so I can call array_search on it ?

Comment: I'm not sure that array_search uses an efficient algorithm, it doesn't seem to care if the input array is ordered. That means it's either a linear search or it sorts the array first anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP doesn't have a good clean way of doing this that I know of. However, you can do it yourself using a binary-search since the array is already sorted by the values in the first column of its child arrays. Here is the code to accomplish this:

```
<?php
// Binary Search Taken By greenmr:
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#89413
function array_bsearch( $needle, $haystack, $comparator ) {
    $high = Count( $haystack ) -1;
    $low = 0;

    while ( $high >= $low ){
        $probe = Floor( ( $high + $low ) / 2 );
        $comparison = $comparator( $haystack[$probe], $needle );
        if ( $comparison < 0 ) {
            $low = $probe +1;
        } elseif ( $comparison > 0 ) {
            $high = $probe -1;
        } else {
            return $probe;
        }
    }

  return -1;
}

// Compare the needle the first element/column 
function KeyCompare( $obj, $needle) {
    if ( $obj[0] < $needle ) {
        return -1;
    } elseif ( $obj[0] > $needle ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

$arr = array(array(0=>"homer", 1=> 1, 2=> 2, 3=> 3),
        array(0 => "marge", 1=> 2, 2 => 4, 3=> 8),
        array(0 => "bart", 1 => 6, 2 => 2, 3 => 7),
        array(0 => "lisa", 1 => 16, 2 => 20, 3 => 71));

$index = array_bsearch( 'marge', $arr, 'KeyCompare' );

// prints the array containing marge
echo print_r($arr[$index]);
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a PHP function similar to array_search, which I can use to search for matching items in the 1st column of the 2D array?

You could use [array_filter](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$matchedArray = array_filter($myArray, function($x) use ($nameToSearchFor) {
    return $x[0] == $nameToSearchFor;
});
```

Then given:

```
$myArray = array(
    array(0=>"homer", 1=> 1, 2=> 2, 3=> 3),
    array(0 => "marge", 1=> 2, 2 => 4, 3=> 8),
    array(0 => "bart", 1 => 6, 2 => 2, 3 => 7),
    array(0 => "lisa", 1 => 16, 2 => 20, 3 => 71),
);

$nameToSearchFor = "bart";
```

Would produce:

```
 $matchedArray === array(0 => "bart", 1 => 6, 2 => 2, 3 => 7);
```

I've used [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), that only work in PHP 5.3.0, but you use a traditional callback or [create_function](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) in older versions of php

> Failing that, is there a PHP function to copy the first column into a 1D array (whilst preserving order) so I can call array_search on it ?

See **deceze**'s first option. I see no need repeating a perfectly good answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
$oneDarray = array_map(create_function('$a', 'return $a[0];'), $twoDarray);
```

Or:

```
foreach ($twoDarray as $values) {
    if ($values[0] == 'homer') {
        // found!
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question came top on my Google search for `array search column`. It took me some time to find [this better answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24470525/2302623). [By Mark M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2253331/mark-m).

> If you are using `PHP >= 5.5`, then you can use the new [**array_column()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), >in conjunction with [**array_keys()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [**array_map()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

Applied to this question, to search for "bart", it would be:

```
$array=array(
    array(0=>"homer", 1=> 1, 2=> 2, 3=> 3),
    array(0 => "marge", 1=> 2, 2 => 4, 3=> 8),
    array(0 => "bart", 1 => 6, 2 => 2, 3 => 7),
    array(0 => "lisa", 1 => 16, 2 => 20, 3 => 71));

$result = $array[array_search("bart",array_column($array, 0))];
print_r($result);

/* Output:
    Array
    (
        [0] => bart
        [1] => 6
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 7
    )
*/
```

[**Run demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/94919f72c6b398a6c9a4acbb86c9173a8e825f3c)

Comment: This advice is flawed because `array_search()` will return `false` when no match is found.  That false will be treated as `0` and will give the first subarray when the result should be no subarray.  `maggie` returns `homer`'s row: https://3v4l.org/ZWlQM

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the array to use keys using an array_walk

```
$new_data = array();
array_walk($data, create_function('a','$new_data[$a[0]] = $a;'));
$search_text = 'bart';
if (array_key_exists($new_data, $search_text)) {
    echo "I found '$search_text': ".print_r($new_data[$search_text], true);
}
```