# PHP Search Array column for match

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have an array as below, which has multiple columns. I want to search in the first column for a specific value, and have the rows that match returned. Is that possible to do?

For example:

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [column2] => value2 [column3] => value3 [column4] => value4 [column5] => value5 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [column2] => value2 [column3] => value3 [column4] => value4 [column5] => value5 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [column2] => value2 [column3] => value3 [column4] => value4 [column5] => value5 
)
```

So let's say I want to search the "id" column for "1" and have the results displayed. How can this be done? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have an nested `Array` you need two iterations:

```
$filtered = array();
$rows = Your Array;
foreach($rows as $index => $columns) {
    foreach($columns as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'id' && $value == '1') {
            $filtered[] = $columns;
        }
    }
}
```

This should do the job.

Comment: Bonus question: How would I be able to know how many results were found (so how many rows were returned in the array)? Is that possible to do? Thank you!

Comment: To get the number of items in an `Array` use `count()` function. Like `$num_results = count($filtered)`.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using `PHP >= 5.5`, then you can use the new [**array_column()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), in conjunction with [**array_keys()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [**array_map()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

Given your array, `$array`:

```
$keys = array_keys(array_column($array, 'id'), 1);
$new_array = array_map(function($k) use ($array){return $array[$k];}, $keys);
```

[**See demo**](http://3v4l.org/IoDA9)

Answer (score 2):

I found a much simpler solution that I think is worthwhile sharing with the world

`in_array(1, array_column($yourArray, 'id'));`

Tested on PHP >= 5.5

Comment: This checks the existence of, but not the location of the rows containing the needle.  This doesn't provide the output detailed in the question.

Answer (score 2):

These steps will always return a row in an array that uses a unique id column (in this example in the first column, 0)

1) Get an array of just IDs

`$ids = array_column($my_table, 0);`

2) Find the row with my ID

`$row_index = array_search($id, $ids);` (where $id is a certain ID)

3) Then I could use

`$my_table[$row_index][n]` (where n is a given column)

Answer (score 1):

Use this function :

```
global $result;
function array_searc_result($array,$key,$value)
{
    global $result;
    foreach($array as $k=>$v)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($key,$v) && ($v[$key] == $value))
        {
            $result[] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $result;;
}
$data = array_searc_result($array,'id',2);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

$array is your given array variable.

Comment: Works just fine without the use of Globals.
Also, be aware of the quasi-typo in the function name.

Answer (score 0):

I use this helper to find matches by key / value:

```
function array_search_by_key($array, $key, $value) {
    if(!is_array($array)) {
        return [];
    }
    $results = [];
    foreach($array as $element) {
        if(isset($element[$key]) && $element[$key] == $value) {
            $results[] = $element;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```